# syntax error when trying to call JPA function with custom query

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2, jpql

Inside my Repository, i have following

```java
public interface TenantRepository extends JpaRepository<Tenant, UUID> {
    ...

    @Query("select substring(email from '@(.*)$') as domain from Tenant group by domain")
    public List<String> findAllDomain();
}
```

When i tried to excute it, i got an error which says:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "select substring(tenant0_.email, [*]from, '@(.*)ParseError: KaTeX parse error: Can't use function '\)' in math mode at position 2: '\̲)̲&nbsp;as&nbsp;c…') as col_0_0_ from tenants tenant0_ group by col_0_0_
```

So i change the query to this:

```sql
"select substring(email from '@(.*)\\$') as domain from Tenant group by domain"
```

But it got another error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "select substring(tenant0_.email, [*]from, '@(.*)\\$') as col_0_0_ from tenants tenant0_ group by col_0_0_"; expected "INTERSECTS (, NOT, EXISTS, UNIQUE, INTERSECTS"; SQL statement:
select substring(tenant0_.email, from, '@(.*)\$') as col_0_0_ from tenants tenant0_ group by col_0_0_
```

When i try the query on my PgAdmin4, it works.

Any suggestions?

thx.

Comment: Your substring() method has SQL keywords in it. Lookup JPA substring() function or whatever DB it is for use of substring function syntax requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to get all the email domains.
In JPA you can use combination of locate and substring functions to achieve this

```
    @Query("select substring(t.email, locate('@', t.email) + 1) as domain from Tenant t group by domain")
    public List<String> findAllDomain();
```

emails in db

```
aaa@domain1.com
bbbb@domain2.com
ccccccc@domain2.com
```

query response

```
domain1.com, domain2.com
```